# Structure objects within deque - lisp/scheme interpreter

Tags: c++, data-structures, data-manipulation

I've been having trouble making of creating instances of new structures within a deque in c++. This is my own attempt at a lisp/scheme interpreter.

Here is the code I have below:

```
void store_info(stack_block *tree, deque<string> tokens){

cout << "level: " << counter << "\n"; 

while(temp != tokens.size()){
    if(tokens[temp] == "("){
        tree->lvl.push_back(tokens[temp]);
        temp = temp + 1;
        counter = counter + 1;
        tree->branches.push_back(createstack());
        store_info(tree2->branches.back(), tokens, index); //recursive call
    }
    else if(tokens[temp] == ")"){
        tree->lvl.push_back(tokens[temp]);
        temp = temp + 1;
        return;
    }
    else {
        tree->lvl.push_back(tokens[temp]);
        temp++;
    }
}
```

Tokens is a deque type containing strings which are various tokens broken up like so

> { "(", "define", "function", "(", "x", "y", ")", ")" }

where the commas separate the tokens. The temp and counter variables are global ints.
The tree variable is a structure like so (with global shown) within a header file:

```
    struct stack_block{ //holds the nested situations
        deque<string> lvl;
        deque<stack_block*> branches;
    };

    stack_block* createstack(){
        stack_block *result = new stack_block;
        return result;
    };

int temp = 0;
int counter = 0;
```

I have been attempting to get results such as this:

```
./program
    Level 1: ( define function ( 
    Level 2: x y))
```

or

```
./program
Level 1: define function (x y)
Level 2: xy)
```

When I actually get this:

```
EVAL
Level 1:define function ( )
```

This is how I print the following information:

```
string evaluate(deque<string> tokens, variables *functions, string u_input, stack_block *tree){

    deque<stack_block*>::iterator j;
    deque<string>::iterator i;
    int k = 1;

    cout << "\nEVAL\n";

    for(j = tree->branches.begin(); j != tree->branches.end(); j++){
        printf("Level %d:" , k);
        for(i = (*j)->lvl.begin(); i != (*j)->lvl.end(); i++){
            cout << *i << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        k++;
    }

    return "Something went wrong";
}
```

This evaluate function is currently underdeveloped until I can the user input parsed right.

Anyone have any suggestions? Any advice is appreciated

If you're wondering about the main function, it is simply a function parsing the user input and calls a function that results in the tokenized strings deque.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass `tokens` by value? If you're not modifying it pass it as a reference to a constant `deque` instead, and if you're modifying it pass it as non-constant reference.

Comment: Also, you should really learn how to use a debugger, as then you can step through the code, line by line, entering functions when needed, and monitor variables and their values as they change.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?